# c# 4.0 service as client to connect a signalr(1.2.2) hub

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-services, signalr.client

I worte a server class as **DLTransMonCore.cs** using C# .Net 4.0.

*DLTransMonCore.cs* in DLTransMonCore DLL Project

```
public void MonStart() {
    var client = new WebSignalrClient();
    client.HubUrl = "http://10.20.30.40/MyApp";
    client.HubName = "MyAppHub";
    client.InitialSignalrHub();
}
```

*WebSignalrClient.cs* in WebSignalrClient DLL Project

```
public string HubUrl;
public string HubName;
public void InitialSignalrHub() {
    var hubConnection = new HubConnection(HubUrl);
    var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(HubName);
    hubConnection.Start().Wait();
}
```

This server will connect to a web site by using signalr(1.2.2). And listen some ports use socket as a socket server.

1st Scenario, 
I use a **console application** (**Program.cs**) to instance the DLTransMonCore class and start it.
Everything is work fine.

*Program.cs*

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var core = new DLTransMonCore();
    core.MonStart();
    Console.Readkey();
}
```

2nd Scenario, 
I make a **windows service** (**Service1.cs**) to instance DLTransMonCore class and start it. When I try to launch the "Service1" in Windows Services, the "Service1" will start for about 10 seconds and then auto stopped by Windows.

*Service1.cs*

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    var core = new DLTransMonCore();
    core.MonStart();
}
```

I wrote a log file to find which line last executed was: 
**hubConnection.Start().Wait();** (in WebSignalrClient.cs),

and it never reach the next line.

3rd Scenario, 
I make another **windows service** (**Service2.cs**) to instance WebSignalrClient directly. And this "Service2" start successfully. (hubConnection.Start().Wait(); is executed successfully and reach the next line)

*Service2.cs*

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    var client = new WebSignalrClient();
    client.HubUrl = "http://10.20.30.40/MyApp";
    client.HubName = "MyAppHub";
    client.InitialSignalrHub();
}
```

Why the Service1 be fail and the Service2 be success?

Any comment will be appreciate!

**Edit:**
**The description of this post is simplify from my "Original Solution". The Original Solution has lots of Models, Repositories, Interfaces, Utilities, Extensions, Projects...etc.

So I have to simplify it to describe my problem.**

**But I just created another "New Solution", with the minimized code to test Scenario2 and Scenario3.**
**Then I found the "New Solution" were worked. It's really bother me...**

**Now I have to retest and review my code in the "Original Solution".**

But if you have any suggestions or comments, please still comment it.
Thank you!

**Edit 2:**
Dear all, This pattern is no problem.
I found my problem in the "Original Solution".
The problem is : NullReferenceException.
The reason is : When Windows starts the Service, the working directory **IS NOT** where your Service.exe existed.
In my solution, I have my customize configuration file in that Service's location. And the Service will get the configuration by using the filename directly. Then, the Service will got a null object, and the NullReferenceException when Service Starting is trying to access the config.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why but i had the same issue as i wanted a self hosted server using windows service and i never figured out why it was so unstable, what i can suggest is to use Owin selfhost as i switched to it using signalR and it's much more reliable than windows service.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but this OS of my server is WinSrv2003. The latest version of .Net framework that they can support is .Net 4.0, and Signalr is 1.2.2. The Selfhost Signalr is version 2.0 or above. So that I can't use that solution.

Comment: BTW, I found my test-case has something incorrect. I have to re-edit it to avoid misleading readers.